# Prettier removes whitespace after comma

Tags: javascript, whitespace, prettier, formatter, removing-whitespace

I want a white space after a comma. But whenever I save the code, prettier removes the comma and white space. Is there any way to prevent prettier from removing white space ?

Expected code:  `tl.to('li', { opacity: 1, stagger: 1 },   );`

Code I get after saving:  `tl.to('li', { opacity: 1, stagger: 1 });`

Comment: Why? Trailing optional arguments in a list should not have a trailing comma before them.

Comment: This is getting cleaned up because it looks like extraneous code. What's the requirement for having it?

Comment: We should start a separate exchange site for VSCode, Vim, Brackets etc.

Comment: @Dimitar I wouldn't edit out the spaces in the code in this case. For all we know, the author wants to keep those in. Not saying that it's a good idea to do so, just I think that this conflicts with the author's intent.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance Didn't keep track of the edits. I thought somebody put them there to satisfy the required minimum 10 characters to make an edit.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance As I suspected, the edit was made by tadman  to add the extra 2 spaces. The original question had only one space. Also, this should not be downvoted, it should be closed. I mean, his name is "MemeDriveDev" after all.

Comment: @Dimitar It only rendered that way after the markup. Here's the original source: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/688c971a-74a1-47ae-a28e-9f8ce9b73805/view-source

Comment: I am newbie to programming and learning GSAP library. In a tutorial video, the instructor has given a space after a comma. I see that it's a bad practice, But if I have to use space after coma, how can I achieve this? Prettier doesn't allow this. Also, please don't go after my username 

Comment: If you absolutely *must* (like for a grade or something), then probably turning off Prettier is the best option. I hear it's rather insistent on certain things and doesn't come with a lot of configuration capability. If it's not actually necessary, I would just let Prettier do its thing and just accept that the instructor's code isn't going to match mine all the time.

Comment: In my 5 years of professional programming and 8 more years of programming at school and at home, I have never used prettier or something similar. I like to format my own code the way I like it, according to my standard. or the standard of the people on my team. I'd turn off prettier. Furthermore, your code doesnt have to *exactly* match the tutorial or instructor. I.e. saying `a == b` and `b == a` is the same thing just as calling `a(5, )` is same as calling `a(5)`. functionally, it makes absolutely zero difference. Aesthetically, the second call is better.

Answer (score 0):

try adding prettier-ignore comment like below.

```
// prettier-ignore
tl.to('li', { opacity: 1, stagger: 1 },   );
```

Comment: It would be better to implement a global configuration to avoid ignoring each line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).